# Django ManyToMany CreateView Fields In Both Tables

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, create-view

I have two models, there are Book and Author and I add ManyToMany field inside Book model

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name', max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)    

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='title', max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author) # Many to many
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
```

If I want to create CreateView from book and access authors, I can just add code like this

```
class BookCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "books/book_create.html"
    fields = ['title', 'authors']
```

but something that I want to ask is I want to create CreateView from Author model and add field named **books** inside it. I tried to code like this

```
class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Author
    template_name = "books/author_create.html"
    fields = ['name', 'books']
```

and it shows an error "Unknown field(s) (books) specified for Author".

help me masters, I'm new in django

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `Author` model don't have a field named `books`, you cannot add that in `AuthorCreateView` fields.

What you should do is first create an instance of `Author` and then add them as author in books instance.

Example.

```
book_instance.authors.add(author_instance)
```

Comment: in which method?

Comment: Well that's upto what you are building.

Answer (score 2):

Now, it is solved by using Form and FormView, this is my code

this is my forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    books = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Book.objects.all())
```

this is my views.py

```
class AuthorCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = "books/author_create.html"
    form_class = AuthorForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        books = form.cleaned_data['books']

        author = Author(name=name)
        author.save()
        book_list = Book.objects.filter(pk__in=books)
        for book in book_list:
            author.book_set.add(book)

        return HttpResponse(author.book_set.all())
```

btw thanks @kartikmaji , you have saved my day :)