# Django CreateView With ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, many-to-many

I am trying to use a Django CreateView and ultimately update a ManyToMany Field if the user selects a certain value.  I can get the form to validate, but ultimately it isn't updating the manytomanyfield in the database.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have referenced this similar SO issue, [Django ManyToMany CreateView Fields In Both Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379714/django-manytomany-createview-fields-in-both-tables) but it was of no help to me.  I recently found this link...[Django CreateView: How to perform action upon save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998300/django-createview-how-to-perform-action-upon-save) and it seems very close to the issue I'm having.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

My code:

```
class AuthorView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = NewAuthor
    form_class = NewAuthorForm
    template_name = 'create_author.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        if instance.status == 'Submitted':

            if instance.choice == "Custom":
                instance.access.add(instance.created_by)  
                form.save_m2m()

    return super(CreateAuthorView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Here is my model:

```
class NewAuthor(models.Model):

CHOICES = (
    ('',''),
    ("Default",Default ),
    ("Custom",Custom ),
)

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ("Submitted","Submitted"),
    ("Pending","Pending")
)

status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default="Submitted",max_length=20)
choice = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES,blank=True,max_length=300)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='created_by_user')    
access = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="new_author_individual_access")
```

This passes form validation, but doesn't save the created_by value in the manytomany field.  I have tried to incorporate form.save(commit=False) and a subsequent form.save(), but that doesn't seem to help either.  I am ultimately trying to add the created_by user to the manytomany field conditionally, but no luck so far.

As a quick update, if I add the form.save_m2m() to my code, it actually does add the created_by to the database...but I also get an error that says object has no attribute 'save_m2m'.  It actually adds the created_by but then quits because of this error.  Now if I add commit=False, no errors but the database doesn't get updated either.

Comment: do you please add your models.py in your description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post was the answer to my problem.  [Save Many-To-Many Field Django Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932426/save-many-to-many-field-django-forms) ModelForms are great....but not with m2m apparently...That was exhausting...

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the value of created_by, you are saving it with a null value since it's the default in your models. Try

```
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.created_by = request.user # or whatever value
    instance.save()
```